# BitBlt not getting its 'aim' consistant

Tags: winapi, point, dpi, bitblt

Windows 11

I have three monitors in front of me. The one on the left has negative screen x coordinates, the centre one starts from zero and the one on the right, a 4K, carries on where the centre one left off. All nice and usual. So I execute

```
BitBlt(hMem2, 0, 0, bmWide, bmHigh, hdc, pt.x, pt.y, SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT);
BitBlt(hMem3, 0, 0, bmWide, bmHigh, hMem2, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
BitBlt(hMem3, 0, 0, bmWide, bmHigh, hMem1, 0, 0, SRCINVERT);
BitBlt(hdc, pt.x, pt.y, bmWide, bmHigh, hMem3, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

to read a block of screen (from hdc), add some overlay and write it back at POINT pt.
Does it? Nope.
It appears about 2000 pixels to the right. Consistently, no matter which monitor I put the test program on. The image painted is exactly what I want with all the screen background from where it came from so the first line is using pt correctly. It has my overlay. If it was landing in the right place it would all be wonderful.

All the hMems are loaded with a nice bitmap to hold the image.

I have tried setting

```
SetMapMode(hMem3, MM_TEXT);
```

to get 1 logical unit = 1 pixel on all of the HDCs.

I have experimented with versions of

```
SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2);
```

but all to no avail. So I'm missing something. pt used as source is not the same as pt used as a destination.

Can anybody tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You'll need to redraw things when the [DPI changes and rescale based on the DPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows). Setting the flag doesn't enable `BitBlt` to do these automagically, you have to do it yourself. The flag just tells windows not to try to do it for you when you can handle it better.

Comment: @Mgetz I tend to agree, except for the fact that the same coordinates are apparently working when used as the source coordinates, and fail when used as the destination coordinates.

Comment: @BenVoigt This is why I avoid `SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext` because in my opinion it's a trap. You have to call it at very specific times (before calling `CreateWindow`* ) or things get weird because there is an internal flag on the window itself that you can't change later. Personally I always use the manifest method *for that exact reason*. So without knowing *when* the OP is calling that it's impossible to guess what's going on.

Comment: Thanks. I don't actually want DPI awareness and I want all the screens on the same DPI but W11 seems to have lost that so they are all set to 100% which M$oft implies is 96dpi. Originally I didn't have SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext() but it showed up in searches on BitBlt() so I tried it at the start of WinMain, I tried it in the function here, never had an effect. The program is a large, quite old thing I wrote decades ago and have tweaked and tweaked to just suit the way I work and this bit used to work, sometimes it still does, and I'd be very sad to loose it.